# sending string between views

Tags: iphone

i have 2 views 
i m sending text in a button on 1st view to label on second  view....

```
//////textfieldtolabelViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "seconview.h"

@interface textfieldtolabelViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet seconview *sec;
    //IBOutlet UITextField *t1;
}

//@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *t1;
-(void)buttonclick:(id)sender;
@end
```

and its .m file is this

```
#import "textfieldtolabelViewController.h"

@implementation textfieldtolabelViewController


-(void)buttonclick:(id)sender
{
    NSString *s = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    //sec.ss = s;
    [sec settext:s];
    [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES]; 
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

now there is second view naming seconview
.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface seconview : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *l1;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *l1;


-(void)settext:(NSString *)ss;
@end
```

and its .m file is ....

```
#import "seconview.h"


@implementation seconview
@synthesize l1;
//@synthesize ss;

-(void)settext:(NSString *)ss
{
    l1.text=ss; 
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

this program did not show any error and runs fine but problem is that the text of button in 1st view does not appear in label on second view
but i made all connection perfectly.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the     [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES]; should be above the setText 
try it

```
-(void)buttonclick:(id)sender
{
    NSString *s = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    //sec.ss = s;

    [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];


    [sec settext:s];

}
```

hope it  will work....

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't connect `l1` to the actual label in the Interface Builder. Verify with the debugger, that `l1` is not `nil` in your settext method

Comment: no brother i did this fine
but still not working.....
please check the code and reply please.....
im waiting

Answer (score 0):

You can include the view controller containing the label in the view controller where you want it to change, and access it by allocating a copy of it.

For example, use something like this in textfieldtolabelViewController.m

```
#import "seconview.h"

-(void)buttonclick:(id)sender
{
    NSString *s = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    seconview *viewcontroller = [[seconview alloc] initWithNibName:@"seconview" bundle:nil];
    [[viewcontroller l1] setText:s];
    [viewcontroller release];
    [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES]; 
}
```